# How do I get the letter spacing from a TextAppearance

Tags: android, android-layout

We are using a library which contains all styling such as letter spacing. This has caused some issues in our custom views as we have needed to use the TextAppearance correctly.

I am passing in the TextAppearance through the XML and tried to use it's property on a paint. This has worked with other properties such as text size and FontTypeFace but doesn't work due to the lack of a `textAppearanceSpan.getLetterSpacing()` function.

The XML's are passed through a declared styleable

**attrs.xml**

```
<declare-styleable name="MyCustomView">
    <attr name="TextAppearance" />
</declare-styleable>
```

**layout.xml**

```
<MyCustomView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:TextAppearance="?attr/TextAppearanceBig" />
```

I then read these elements in

**MyCustomView.java**

```
Paint mPaint;
public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyCustomView, 0, 0);
    int textAppearanceID = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyCustomView_TextApperance);
    TextAppearanceSpan textAppearanceSpan = new TextAppearanceSpan(context, textApperanceID);

    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setTextSize(textAppearanceSpan.getTextSize());
    mPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(textAppearanceSpan.getFamily(), Typeface.NORMAL);
}

@Override
protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.drawText("Hello World", 0, 0, mPaint);
}
```

I want to do `mPaint.setLetterSpacing(textAppearanceSpan.getLetterSpacing())` but the function `textAppearanceSpan.getLetterSpacing()` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

[getLetterSpacing()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getLetterSpacing()) is method of Paint class so you can use it with `paint` object.

Its by default value is 0

[setLetterSpacing (float letterSpacing)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setLetterSpacing(float)) is method of `TextView`

Thank you.

Comment: Yes I plan to set the LetterSpacing of the paint object, but for that I need to read the LetterSpacing from the TextAppearance.

Comment: Default is 0. if you want to get it after updated, you can use `paint.getLetterSpaning();`

Comment: I wonder how to read the letter spacing from a TextAppearance. I know how to apply it to a paint. Thanks anyway!